# Javascript animation loop wont stop

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Im a beginner making a basic web page that has an animation of text going from the top of the screen to the middle when the page loads. The animation itself works great, but Im having trouble stopping the loop. The animation itself stops, but I think the function is continually looping. As such, other elements on the web page such as links and the like don't function correctly as the javascript technically isnt done. How would I go about ending the function? Thanks.

```
window.onload = Animation;
function Animation() {

//Get Element, Use Position to detemrine text's position.

var Element = document.getElementById("AnimationText");
var Position = -500;

var ID = setInterval(OnFrame, 20);

function OnFrame() {

    if (Position > 50) {

        clearInterval(ID);

    } else {

        if (Position > -100 && Position <= 0)  {

            //Middle of animation, while text is between -100 and 0 position.
            Position = Position + 3;

        } else if (Position > 0) {

            //End of animation until text position is > 50.
            Position = Position + 2;

        } else {

            //Start of animation until text position is at -100.
            Position = Position + 4;

        }

        Element.style.top = Position + 'px';

    }

}

}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype HTML>

<HTML>

<head>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sedgwick+Ave" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href = "HomepageStyle.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">

    <script src = "HomepageAnimation.js"></script>


</head>


<body>

    <div id = "AnimationText">

            <h1>TNT</h1>

    </div>

    <center>

    <a href = "LogIn.html">

        <img src = "_assets/LoginButtonHome.png" style = "margin-right: 40px; margin-top: 400px;">

    </a>

    </center>

</body>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Recommended background music while you debug this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JhqyZeUlE8U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out your code in a test html file and added console logs to see if the function is getting called even after `clearInterval`. It doesn't. You can test it yourself. Add two `console.log` statements, one in the if and another in the else.

However, you can also try this if it solves your problem:

```
if (Position > 50) {
    clearInterval(ID);
    console.log("ended"):
    ID = null;
    return;
}
```

Also this is my test html element:

```
<p id="hello" style="position: absolute;">My first paragraph.</p>
```

JSFiddle link: [Test here!](http://jsfiddle.net/vg6fq9uw/)

You can view console logs in Chrome by:
View -> Developer -> JavaScript Console

Comment: Hey - the other link on the page still isn't working (I know it has to do with the animation because if its removed, the link works fine.) In case there was any confusion, the function, the function always executed on that if statement, but for some reason it isnt stopping the loop. Thanks.

Edit: AFter a little more experimentation, it appears that the loop does end. Yet the links aren't working. Im honestly stumped...

Comment: can you paste in your sample html as well

Comment: Sure! Edited the original post with it.

Comment: I just tested the code. I have created another jsfiddle. check it. it's working fine. the link is also working if clicked during the animation. test this. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qerhs8db/5/)

Comment: Hey - thanks for the help. It was actually a CSS issue. My divs were overlapping due to some styling error. Thanks for the effort tho!

Answer (score 0):

Use JS just to add the new class and let CSS hadle the rest:

HTML:

```
<div id = "AnimationText" class="init">
  <h1>TNT</h1>
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("AnimationText").classList.add("middle");
```

CSS:

```
#AnimationText {
  transition: all 5s ease;
}
.init {
  margin-top: -200px;
}
.middle {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 250px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/haev137u/1/